# Overal Coherence in Gensim and Mallet

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I would like to know how the overall coherence is measured for u_mass', 'c_v', 'c_uci', 'c_npmi' for each set of topics in the gensim (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/coherencemodel.html)?

Is it based on the average of coherence values: (coherence topic 1 + coherence topic 2 + .... + coherence topic n)/n ?

For example, if we have 5 topics, the overall coherence would be (coherence topic 1 + coherence topic 2 + coherence topic 3 + coherence topic 4 + coherence topic 5) divided by 5

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the overall coherence of a model is the average coherence of topics (meaning your example of five topics is correct).  `C_v`, `C_uci`, `C_npmi`, and `C_u_mass` are all slightly different coherence metrics, all based on pointwise mutual information.

There is a good survey paper that details all of the above coherence metrics that can be found [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/2684822.2685324?casa_token=g63nubpyx-gAAAAA:eGGgeCYO8cWiT2M57fUni7SyFmokdYqNvE3L_sCdVbdNiyblSge78HsVvuspXNXoITJiWgreMktx).